# UIDatepicker showing one day before

Tags: ios8, xcode6, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I've set the datepicker's maximum date to taday:

```
[self.picker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
```

When I play with the date picker, previous dates work fine.
But if I try to choose A future date and then previous dates, it always shows one day before the actual chosen one.

for example: when I choose 11th may 2015, it shows:
2015-05-10 21:00:00 +0000

I think the problem is something around the time or time zone, but I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution,
Only after converting the NSDate to string format, the date was correct.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];
```